# A Task App for each project site or better once shared Task app on the top-site?

Tags: tasks, project-templates

I have a dilema regarding tasks and project sites.

Suppose I have a top site and it has some child-sites which are project sites. I want to track tasks for each project site independently but also I would like to have a task overview (e.g. with the top 10 tasks) in my top site.

Here I have two choices: 
1) Each project site has an app Tasks (with its timeline). In my top-site I create a list that merge all the project tasks and filter it.
2) I have a unique Task app in my top-site with a column "project ID" and each project site will include a view of this task filtering by the project ID (here I don't know if I will lose the timeline widget).

Which is the best solution? Thanks in advance.
Best regards,

Daniel

Answer (score 0):

I'm in a similar dilema.

To avoid having multiple task apps for each project I just made one master tasks app on the root site for all projects. this is because our supervisor wanted an overview of everything.

Currently I'm using the task item unique ID as a project number. (Which also shows unique IDs for sub tasks which isn't ideal. We may make a custom workflow in SharePoint designer to make unique IDs to fix this.

As far as you having a view for each project site....
What we've done so far is place a tasks web app on the home page, which can have a view. We set the view to "my tasks" but one could make and choose a view that filters a specific project. That would mean a lot of custom views to make over time though. 
But, as long as you set the view to show the timeline, it will show up in the web app as well. Not sure if the timeline would show only a specific project though.